Inconsistent y-or-n-p prompt behavior in Emacs Lisp
I have the following Emacs Lisp code:
(progn
  (y-or-n-p "Test: ")
  (let ((search-spaces-regexp "\\(?:\n?[\s\t]+\\|\n\\)?"))
    (y-or-n-p "Test: ")))

The first prompt from the y-or-n-p function appears as expected:
Test: (y or n)

However, the second prompt appears differently:
Test: (\‘y’ or \‘n’)

I'm trying to understand why the second prompt format changes. What causes this inconsistency in the y-or-n-p prompt?
I suspect it might be related to the search-spaces-regexp variable or how Emacs handles interactive prompts, but I'm not sure. Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated!
Note added. I submitted a bug report: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=71429

Why do you have to modify search-spaces-regexp? Its doc string would make me weary about changing it, but you might have a good reason. If you cannot accomplish your goal any other way, maybe you can refactor your code, so that the let-binding of search-spaces-regexp does not affect y-or-n-p and only affects what you really want to affect.

You provide Emacs with a totally unexpected regular expression:
\(?:\n?[\s\t]+\|\n\)?
                    ^

(BTW you wrote one more duplicate backslash before the first n.)
It makes no sense to add a ? at the end of the group.  
Even worse, it makes Emacs consider an empty string consist of whitespaces.
This regexp is not malformed, but hardly anyone writes it.  
So I don't think Emacs maintainers need to modify the original functions to accommodate this edge case.

The problem is due to a call to one of the search-related functions in substitute-command-keys.
(substitute-command-keys
 "(\\`y' or \\`n') ")
#("(y or n) " 1 2 (font-lock-face help-key-binding face help-key-binding) 6 7 (font-lock-face help-key-binding face help-key-binding))

(let ((search-spaces-regexp "\\(?:\n?[\s\t]+\\|\n\\)?"))
  (substitute-command-keys
   "(\\`y' or \\`n') "))
"(\\‘y’ or \\‘n’) "



"Even worse, it makes Emacs consider an empty string consist of whitespaces."
This is exactly what I want. I need it to match both \newcommand{ and \newcommand { with the regexp \\\\newcommand\s{. I have no doubts about my use of this regexp. I've been using it for years without ever having had any problems (apart from the one described in my question).


@Gabriele Maybe this can be sent as a bug report if you really want your regexp to work perfectly

Ok, I'll try to submit a bug report. Thanks!
